# Win32 exception upon releasing virtualbox

Tags: python, multithreading, virtualbox, pywin32

I'm trying to run Virtualbox within a thread. During the second iteration of the while loop, where the th variable gets reasigned, the app crashes and produces a Win32 exception. This seems to be caused by the release of the vbox and session. My question is how I do I properly release them manually?

```
Win32 exception occurred releasing IUnknown at 0x035e40b8
Win32 exception occurred releasing IUnknown at 0x04babcb0
```

The basics of my application (virtualbox from pyvbox and virtualbox sdk)

```
import virtualbox
import threading
import time


class ThreadExecutor(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.vbox = None
        self.session = None
        self.vm = None
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        self.vbox = virtualbox.VirtualBox()
        self.session = virtualbox.Session()
        self.vm = self.vbox.find_machine("Ubuntu")
        self.vm.launch_vm_process(self.session, 'gui', '')

        time.sleep(30)
        if int(self.session.state) == 1:
            print('Boot failed!')
            return
        else:
            print('Powering down')
            self.session.console.power_down()
        print('Operation completed')
        return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        print('Input')
        if input():
            th = ThreadExecutor()
            th.start()
            print('Thread started')

            time.sleep(5)
            while th.isAlive():
                print('App running')
                time.sleep(5)
            print('Execution finished')
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback (although being raised from a thread this might be difficult :) ). Enclose the faulty lines of code in `try:` / `except:` and also print the traceback: `traceback.print_exc()`, and add that info to the question

Comment: I tried enclosing the code in run with at try, except and traceback.print_exc() in except but the app crashes before traceback gets printed.

Comment: The code from `def run(self):`?

Comment: Yes, the crash happens at reassignment of `self.vbox` and `self.session` so I enclosed the whole reassignment code in try-except with `traceback` in the except block.

Comment: https://github.com/SethMichaelLarson/virtualbox-python/issues/114
This seems to be a unsolved issue with threading and pyvbox.

Comment: Did you try running `th.run()` manually (ion the main thread) twice, to see if the problem persists?

Comment: That actually worked with a sleep between reassigning. Any idea why?

Comment: Moving the *VBox* initialization stuff to *\_\_init\_\_* fixed the problem for me. Did it for you? I suspect that when doing that from *run*, at the end of *run*, all the objects are destroyed, (which happens too soon, I'd say), while in the other case they are destroyed when the *ThreadExecutor* object is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

To release the session reliable you should use a try/except/finally construction like this:

```
try:
   #Your code
except:
   print("something unexpected happend")
finally:
   self.session.console.power_down()
```

Comment: This only catches the exception and doesn't prevent the application from crashing.

Comment: It catches an exception, yes. And the finally statement is used to run code each time, even in the event of an exception. This way you make sure your resource is always released.

Comment: Well puting the whole run code into a try, except statement still causes the app to crash.

Comment: This is completely wrong. If it was true, all (main) python files would have a global ***try*** / ***except*** block, and *Python* would never crash.

Comment: @Cristi: If you implement it at the wrong place it is completely wrong, for sure...

Comment: Not sure what' you meant by last comment. My point is that *try* / *except* ... statements are completely useless with crashes (e.g. *segfault*s), like this one appears to be. So surrounding the code in such a block will have no effect.

Comment: Then you should read my answer again. It was about how to release the session reliably and not how to fix the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code (without running it):

- Fixing (stuff that wasn't right) and some reorganizing
- Additional printing

in order to work and debug the issue (with **no intention to fix it whatsoever** - at least not at this stage).

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import virtualbox
import threading
import time


DEFAULT_DEBUG_MSG_INDENT = "    "


def debug(text, indent_count, indent=DEFAULT_DEBUG_MSG_INDENT, leading_eoln_count=0):
    print("{:s}{:s}[TID: {:06d}]: {:s}".format("\n" * leading_eoln_count, indent * indent_count, threading.get_ident(), text))


class ThreadExecutor(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.vbox = virtualbox.VirtualBox()
        self.session = virtualbox.Session()
        if not self.vbox or not self.session:
            raise RuntimeError("virtualbox initialization failed")
        self.vm = self.vbox.find_machine("Ubuntu")
        if not self.vm:
            raise ValueError("VM not found")

    def run(self):
        start_wait_time = 15
        debug("Starting VM...", 1)
        self.vm.launch_vm_process(self.session, "gui", "")
        debug("Sleeping {:d} secs...".format(start_wait_time), 1)
        time.sleep(start_wait_time)
        if int(self.session.state) == 1:
            debug("Boot failed!", 1)
            return
        else:
            debug("Powering down", 1)
            self.session.console.power_down()
        debug("Operation completed", 1)


def run(threaded=True):
    debug("RUNNING with{:s} threads".format("" if threaded else "out"), 0, leading_eoln_count=1)
    sleep_time = 5
    while input("{:s}Press ANY key followed by ENTER to continue, ENTER ONLY to queet: ".format(DEFAULT_DEBUG_MSG_INDENT)):
        th = ThreadExecutor()
        if threaded:
            debug("Starting thread...", 0)
            th.start()
            debug("Thread started", 1)
            time.sleep(sleep_time)
            while th.isAlive():
                debug("App running", 1)
                time.sleep(sleep_time)
        else:
            debug("Running...", 0)
            th.run()
        debug("Execution finished", 1)
    debug("Done", 0)


def main():
    run(threaded=False)
    run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

and **it worked!!!**

**Output**:

> ```bat
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q051136288>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
>
> [TID: 036256]: RUNNING without threads
>     Press ANY key followed by ENTER to continue, ENTER ONLY to queet: a
> [TID: 036256]: Running...
>     [TID: 036256]: Starting VM...
>     [TID: 036256]: Sleeping 15 secs...
>     [TID: 036256]: Powering down
>     [TID: 036256]: Operation completed
>     [TID: 036256]: Execution finished
>     Press ANY key followed by ENTER to continue, ENTER ONLY to queet: a
> [TID: 036256]: Running...
>     [TID: 036256]: Starting VM...
>     [TID: 036256]: Sleeping 15 secs...
>     [TID: 036256]: Powering down
>     [TID: 036256]: Operation completed
>     [TID: 036256]: Execution finished
>     Press ANY key followed by ENTER to continue, ENTER ONLY to queet:
> [TID: 036256]: Done
>
> [TID: 036256]: RUNNING with threads
>     Press ANY key followed by ENTER to continue, ENTER ONLY to queet: a
> [TID: 036256]: Starting thread...
>     [TID: 038520]: Starting VM...
>     [TID: 036256]: Thread started
>     [TID: 038520]: Sleeping 15 secs...
>     [TID: 036256]: App running
>     [TID: 036256]: App running
>     [TID: 036256]: App running
>     [TID: 038520]: Powering down
>     [TID: 038520]: Operation completed
>     [TID: 036256]: Execution finished
>     Press ANY key followed by ENTER to continue, ENTER ONLY to queet: a
> [TID: 036256]: Starting thread...
>     [TID: 028884]: Starting VM...
>     [TID: 036256]: Thread started
>     [TID: 028884]: Sleeping 15 secs...
>     [TID: 036256]: App running
>     [TID: 036256]: App running
>     [TID: 036256]: App running
>     [TID: 028884]: Powering down
>     [TID: 028884]: Operation completed
>     [TID: 036256]: Execution finished
>     Press ANY key followed by ENTER to continue, ENTER ONLY to queet:
> [TID: 036256]: Done
> ```

Original code was throwing (only relevant part):

> `pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221008, 'CoInitialize has not been called.', None, None)`

I suspected that moving *virualbox* init stuff in the initializer might be responsible for the behavior change (although as I was saying, I only moved the code because I considered the initializer the right place for it) - that was correct: moving the code back in *run* triggered the exception again.

After a brief inspection of *virtualbox* and *vboxapi* code, I think it has something to do with the place (thread) where *CoInitializeEx* takes place, but I can't put my finger on it.

I also tried to call the function manually (`pythoncom.CoInitializeEx(0)`) in the main block, but `import pythoncom` alone was triggering the exception to appear in the 1<sup>st</sup> iteration.

Comment: I still think the issue is pretty weird. Additionally this isn't the only issue with interaction between threading and virtualbox, se my other [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51057226/different-behaviour-in-normal-and-debug-run-in-threaded-virtualbox). I have therefore moved to using the multiprocessing module instead and have experienced none of the issues with threading.

Comment: The other issue looks the same as this one. Yes it is a weird issue (or at least one that no one understands at this point), most likely because of a faulty 3rd party module. Also, as a general rule,  threading is to be avoided in *Python*. Anyway, what I discovered by (dumb) luck somehow goes around that fault.

Comment: Did this help you reaching your goal?